cannot import name 'ExhaustiveKnnAlgorithmConfiguration' from 'azure.search.documents.indexes.models
I need some help. I've been trying all day to embed documents under upgraded langchain versions (to embed using text-embedding-3-large model). I'm unable to resolve the above problem. I have tried everything I saw online, downgrading the azure-search-documents, downgrading langchain and so. I get either that error or this other one:
(InvalidRequestParameter) The request is invalid. Details: definition : The vector field 'content_vector' must have the property 'vectorSearchProfile' set.
Code: InvalidRequestParameter
Have you been able to resolve it?
Here's my current setup:
azure-core==1.29.7
azure-search-documents==11.4.0b8
langchain==0.1.8 (fails with 0.2.0 as well)
langchain-core==0.2.1
Here's my code:
def set_vector_fields():
    return [
                SimpleField(name="id",type=SearchFieldDataType.String,key=True,filterable=True,),
                SearchableField(name="content",type=SearchFieldDataType.String,searchable=True,),
                SearchField(name="content_vector",
                    type=SearchFieldDataType.Collection(SearchFieldDataType.Single),
                    vector_search_dimensions=dimensionality,
                    searchable=True,
                    vector_search_configuration="hnsw_config"
                    #vector_search_profile_name = "profile_hnsw_config",
                    #vectorSearchProfile="profile_hnsw_config"

                ),
                
                # Additional fields for metadata. Customize as needed based on the structure of the data. See additional footnotes for details
                SearchableField(name="metadata", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, searchable=True,filterable=True,),
                SearchableField(name="id_embedding",type=SearchFieldDataType.String, searchable=True,filterable=True,),
                SimpleField(name="last_update",type=SearchFieldDataType.DateTimeOffset,searchable=True,filterable=True,),
                SearchableField(name="chunk_no",type=SearchFieldDataType.Double,searchable=True,filterable=True,),
                
                #below lists the additional Metadata Fields addded from the CSV file
                SearchableField(name="Filename",type=SearchFieldDataType.String,searchable=True,filterable=True,),
                SearchableField(name="Subject",type=SearchFieldDataType.String,searchable=True,filterable=True,),
                SearchableField(name="Year",type=SearchFieldDataType.String,searchable=True,filterable=True,),
                SearchableField(name="Source",type=SearchFieldDataType.String,searchable=True,filterable=True,),
                
                #Date Fields
                SimpleField(name="Date_File",type=SearchFieldDataType.DateTimeOffset,searchable=True,filterable=True,),
                SimpleField(name="Last_Update_Embedding",type=SearchFieldDataType.DateTimeOffset,searchable=True,filterable=True,)
            ]

#def set_vector_search_config_new():
#    return VectorSearch(algorithms=[HnswAlgorithmConfiguration(
#                                                name="hnsw_config",
#                                                kind=VectorSearchAlgorithmKind.HNSW,
#                                                parameters=HnswParameters(m=8, metric="cosine", ef_construction=400, ef_search=500))],
#                        profiles=VectorSearchProfile(name="profile_hnsw_config",algorithm_configuration_name ="hnsw_config" )
#    )

def set_vector_search_config():
    return VectorSearch(algorithm_configurations=[HnswVectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration(
                                                name="hnsw_config",
                                                kind="hnsw",
                                                parameters=HnswParameters(m=8, metric="cosine", ef_construction=400, ef_search=500))],
                                                        )

The routine fails when I try to call the vector store (in Azure AI Search)
def set_vectorstore(index_name):
            
    embeddings,embedding_function = set_embedding_function()

    fields= set_vector_fields()

    sc_name,scoring_profile =  define_scoring_profile()
    
    # NOTE: IF FAILS HERE, WHEN IT ATTEMPTS TO BUILD THE VECTOR. 
    # I can create the vector, but I can't upload documents via vectorstore.add_documents

    vectorstore: AzureSearch = AzureSearch(
        azure_search_endpoint=azure_search_endpoint,
        azure_search_key=azure_search_key,
        index_name=index_name,
        embedding_function=embedding_function,
        search_type=search_type_GPT,
        fields=fields,
        scoring_profiles = scoring_profile,
        default_scoring_profile = sc_name,

    )
      
    
    return vectorstore

I'll appreciate any help.
Thanks
tried all solutions found online.

You just have to provide a vector profile in fields and create vector search configurations with profile, algorithm, and vectorizers.
Use the code below for getting the index.
def set_vector_fields():
    return [
                SimpleField(name="id",type=SearchFieldDataType.String,key=True,filterable=True,),
                SearchableField(name="content",type=SearchFieldDataType.String,searchable=True,),
                SearchField(name="content_vector",
                    type=SearchFieldDataType.Collection(SearchFieldDataType.Single),
                    vector_search_dimensions=1536, # 1 - 3072
                    vector_search_profile_name="profile_hnsw_config"
                ),
            
                SearchableField(name="metadata", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, searchable=True,filterable=True,),
                SearchableField(name="id_embedding",type=SearchFieldDataType.String, searchable=True,filterable=True,),
                SimpleField(name="last_update",type=SearchFieldDataType.DateTimeOffset,searchable=True,filterable=True,),
                SearchableField(name="chunk_no",type=SearchFieldDataType.Double,searchable=True,filterable=True,),
                
                # Below lists the additional Metadata Fields added from the CSV file
                SearchableField(name="Filename",type=SearchFieldDataType.String,searchable=True,filterable=True,),
                SearchableField(name="Subject",type=SearchFieldDataType.String,searchable=True,filterable=True,),
                SearchableField(name="Year",type=SearchFieldDataType.String,searchable=True,filterable=True,),
                SearchableField(name="Source",type=SearchFieldDataType.String,searchable=True,filterable=True,),
                
                # Date Fields
                SimpleField(name="Date_File",type=SearchFieldDataType.DateTimeOffset,searchable=True,filterable=True,),
                SimpleField(name="Last_Update_Embedding",type=SearchFieldDataType.DateTimeOffset,searchable=True,filterable=True,)     ]

Here, you give the dimension from range 1-3072 since you are using text-embedding-3-large. Refer this for more information.
For vector search configuration, use the code below with vectorizers.
def set_vector_search_config_new():
   return VectorSearch(
        algorithms=[
           HnswAlgorithmConfiguration(
                        name="hnsw_config",
                        kind=VectorSearchAlgorithmKind.HNSW,
                        parameters=HnswParameters(m=8, metric="cosine", ef_construction=400, ef_search=500))],

        profiles=[
           VectorSearchProfile(name="profile_hnsw_config",algorithm_configuration_name ="hnsw_config" ,vectorizer="myOpenAI")],
        vectorizers=[
           AzureOpenAIVectorizer(  
            name="myOpenAI",  
            kind="azureOpenAI",  
            azure_open_ai_parameters=AzureOpenAIParameters(  
                resource_uri=azure_openai_endpoint,  
                deployment_id=azure_openai_embedding_deployment,  
                api_key=azure_openai_key,  
            ),  
        ),  
    ]
   )

Then create the index with the code below.
index_client = SearchIndexClient(endpoint=service_endpoint, credential=credential)  
index = SearchIndex(name=index_name, fields=set_vector_fields(), vector_search=set_vector_search_config_new()) 
result = index_client.create_or_update_index(index) 

Output:

Refer to this documentation for more information.
The error ExhaustiveKnnAlgorithmConfiguration' from 'azure.search.documents.indexes.models is due to a package issue. Try updating the azure-search-documents package to 11.6.0b1.

But I have another question: I have a scoring profile? I used to add it to the AzureSearch vector store setting directly (var scoring_profiles= and default_scoring_profile). That that change? How can I add scoring profile?

Check this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/search-documents-readme?view=azure-python#creating-an-index  above code does create or update the index so create scoring profile and provide it in above code createorupdate function
